# copy app-engine connected android project to another computer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, google-app-engine

I have two mac computers. one running maverick and one running mountain lion. Both computers have eclipse and Google Eclipse Plugin. I have an app-engine connected android project on the mountain lion computer. I want to import it to eclipse on the other computer. Whether I copy to thumb drive, or share folder, or use git is not the issue. Once I have a copy of my project, how do I open it in the new eclipse? Right now, the build path is always broken no matter how I bring it in. And I don't know how to fix the build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that may not be visible is making the project from the old computer incompatible with the development environment in the new computer.  The answer is to not let that affect your projects.  Create a new simple project on the new computer and verify that if works and deploys correctly.  Then import only the source code files from your old project.